# Variable not passing between classes

Tags: java, class, methods, user-input

I have scrapped the old question as it was unclear and with bunch of error and i have found bit easier "i think" solution, although not fully working. 
Revised:::::::: 
LognL Class

```
public final class LogInL extends JFrame {
Connection conn = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
PreparedStatement pst = null;
String Username;
String ID;
public LogInL() {
    initComponents();
    ButtonGroup();         
}

private void backBActionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    LoginMain login = new LoginMain();
    login.setVisible(true);
    this.dispose();
}

private void LoginBActionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    if(prosecutorCB.isSelected())
    {
        try {
            conn = SQLConnect.ConnectDb();
            String sql = "SELECT prosecutors.username, criminalrecords.ID FROM prosecutors, criminalrecords "
                       + "WHERE username = ? and ID = ?";
            pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            pst.setString(1, usernameF.getText());
            pst.setString(2, criminalIdF.getText());

            Username = usernameF.getText();
            System.out.println("Username is " + Username);

            ID = criminalIdF.getText();
            System.out.println("Criminal ID is " + ID);
            rs = pst.executeQuery();
            if(rs.next())
            {
                ProsecutorMain Frame = new ProsecutorMain(); // call Policemain class //display it
                Frame.pack();
                Frame.setVisible(true); // make it visible 
                System.out.println("Welcome to prosecutors");
                this.dispose();
            }
            else
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"<html>wrong username or criminal ID<br>"
                + "Criminal may not longer be in database");
            }
        } 
        catch (SQLException ex) 
        {
            Logger.getLogger(LogInL.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }//end if proseutor


}//end logination

private void ButtonGroup()
{
    ButtonGroup bg = new ButtonGroup();
    bg.add(prosecutorCB);
    bg.add(criminaldefenceCB);
}
```

Revised::::::::
ProsecutorMain class

```
public class ProsecutorMain extends JFrame {
Connection conn = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
PreparedStatement pst = null;
LogInL id = new LogInL();
String UserName;
public ProsecutorMain() throws SQLException 
{
    initComponents();
    UserName = id.Username;
    username.setText(UserName);

    firstname.setText("blablabla");
    incidentlocation.setText("kupa");
    System.out.println(UserName);


} 
private void logOutActionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        int response = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "<html> Are you sure you want to log out?", 
                "Confirm",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
        if (response == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) 
        {

        }
        if (response == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
        {
            this.dispose();
            LogInL login = new LogInL();
            login.setVisible(true);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You have been sucessfully logged out");
        }       
    }
```

Variable in questions is Username

Comment: i guess to help me reorganize the code i have to fulfill my requirement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `UserName` is `null` in `ProsecutorMain` as you are creating a new instance of `LogInL` which does not have the value from the database that the original (and displayed) instance of that `JFrame`.

To fix, you would have to pass in the instance that *does* have `Username` set:

```
public ProsecutorMain(LogInL id) {
   this.id = id;
   ...
}
```

and to create in `LogInL`:

```
new ProsecutorMain(this);
```

---

Rather than creating a new `ProsecutorMain` `JFrame` when you get a result from your query, you could create a custom `LawRecord` with the necessary `username` and `id` fields. You could then pass this to `ProsecutorMain`.

Instead of using 2 `JFrames` here, you could use a modal `JDialog` for accepting the search criteria.

Link: [How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)

Comment: Hello Reimeus could you have a look at the revised question now thank you.

Comment: Can't determine what may or may not be set. If you don't have _too_ much code, please post, otherwise consider posting a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: Questions has een revised with the all relevant code to the question

Comment: Ok i have done as you have suggested but then i got error in LogInL class under "ProsecutorMain Frame = new ProsecutorMain();" i have replaced that with ProsecutorMain Frame = new ProsecutorMain(LogInL id); but still got error.